# Microsoft Access - If Null then

Tags: ms-access, vba

With Microsoft Access, is there a simple way to have a report calculate a sum on the fly and if there are any zeroes/null fields in the total, then disregard those from the equation?

The reason I ask is because I currently am coding a Access report with a bunch of fields for totals of dues collected and as not everyone has paid, my grand total field keeps getting cancelled.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated,

*Update* 
Just found the solution which was right under my nose the entire time. I just had to configure the fields to use a Running Sum (also called a Cumulative Total).

The answer came right from a page in the Microsoft Office Website: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/summing-in-reports-HA001122444.aspx

Comment: Can you please post the solution as an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies about the delayed answer post. When I originally posted my update, I didn't have enough reputation to answer my own question.

As requested below is the solution I found for my problem:

Update Just found the solution which was right under my nose the entire time. I just had to configure the fields to use a Running Sum (also called a Cumulative Total).

The answer came right from a page in the Microsoft Office Website: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/summing-in-reports-HA001122444.aspx